# How To Deal With Card Printers Through C#

Tags: c#, printing, report

**Hi Guys

i have a general question

in my company we have a card printer named (EDI Secure DCP 360i) . they want me to make a program to deal with this printer and print cards through it

i never made such a program that deals with devices .
any suggestion on how to do this ?? or is there any reference  that i can use to help me in this issue

any help will be appreciated .

Thanks**

Comment: Did you try _anything_ so far? This is not a good question for here.

Comment: I would either start by checking the manufacturers website or the instruction manual that came with it (it may have even come with a disk..)

Comment: A good rule of thumb is that if a question can't be answered in a paragraph or two, it may be a bit too broad. This answer would more or less require including and annotating the printer manual.

Comment: you're probably going to have to write something that communicates with the printer directly, unless the manufacturer supplies a dll you can use. Read the manual and talk to the manufacturer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The card printer is just a printer. So create your program to do whatever is needed, create the cards as an image or report. Then you should be able to print to the Card Printer.